# How can I get the binary data from a Class[_] object?

Tags: java, scala, reflection

I want to send class data over a network, and I need to get the binary data in the .class files, from the name of the class. I would like to use the default classloader and then send the loaded data over the network. How can I do this? I'm using scala 2.9.0.1 and jre6

Comment: Do you want to send the data in your instance of your class our the byte code for the class itself?

Comment: I'm using scala remote actors. After the connection is set up I send an instance of my class from the server to the client. And if while deserializing I can't find the class definition, I send a request for it to the server. And the problem is here, I can't find out what to send back if the server is packaged in a jar file.

Answer (score 4):

RMI lets you load class files from across the network. That's probably easier than rolling your own solution. Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/codebase.html

Comment: The whole thing is setup and working if I know the path to the .class file. But if I want to package it in a jar it fails because I can't determine the path to the class files.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the periods in the fully qualified class name with file separators and append ".class" to the result, this will be the location of the .class file within your classpath.  Then use the ClassLoader to access the file as a stream.

```
val location = className.replaceAll("\\.",File.separator) + ".class"
val stream = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(location)
//send the stream to your remote location
```

Comment: It should pick up anything in your classpath whether it's in a jar or not.  If you are having trouble I'd guess that the issue is more likely which ClassLoader you are using.  If you were trying this on a class named MyClass, try something like this: MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(....)